# DMS-59 to VGA and DVI?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, dvi, vga

One of the users I support wants a dual monitor setup. He has two monitors, one with a VGA input and one with a DVI input. He also has a SFF Dell Optiplex that uses half-height cards, so options are a bit limited (as is budget...) with regards to what I can put in it.

I have found a cheap Radeon X1300 SE half-height card that has a DMS-59 port on it. I know it's possible to get DMS-59 to 2xVGA and DMS-59 to 2xDVI and even DMS-59 to 1xVGA and 1xDVI splitter cables. It's the last one I'm interested in, but I wondered if there was anything the card itself would have to support for it to work as the blurb only says it does 2xVGA or 2xDVI.

From my rudimentary research and understanding, it [would appear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:DMS59_pinout.svg) that DMS-59 outputs two VGA signals and two DVI signals at the same time. If the card supports both two VGA outputs and two DVI outputs, then my logic is that a clever cable could show one of each at the same time.

So uh... any ideas on whether it'll work even though the card says nothing about support for VGA and DVI simultaneously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small form factor Dell Optiplex.  What... a GX270 that has either had blown capacitors replaced/motherboard with blown caps replaced, or will NEED them replaced?  One of those Optiplex?

I only ask, because are you looking for an AGP half Height card?  Are you fixed on that Radeon X1300 because of some review?  Are you limited to only PCI cards?  I know that Superuser isn't the Shopping Network, so I know you aren't looking for different cards to purchase and whatnot...

That DMS-59 is supposed to be more than a simple splitter, so the VGA/DVI version should work as your client wants.  However, if you want to be sure, just buy [this card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814139010) instead.  It is PCI, so whether or not the Optiplex has an AGP slot this will work, it comes with two low profile brackets (one for the card and the DVI, and the other for the VGA on a pigtail).

Comment: It's an Optiplex 780 SFF, so it needs to be PCI Express. I'm not fussed about what kind of card it is, but this is academia, so the biggest constraint is budgetary.

Comment: There are multiple PCI-E low-profile ready cards out there that are exactly the same... two brackets, one to mount to the card that will give access to the DVI port, and a second bracket that the VGA port mounts to on a pigtail.  This one should fit the bill and budget http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814500220